# Does building with angular-cli add new user agent stylesheet?

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-cli, stylesheet

I am in the process of trying to run a hybrid angularjs and angular 8 application.  I am using angular cli to build/run the application.

I am currently stuck trying to figure out why a few user agent styles are different between my old angularjs application and the new hybrid application.

For instance the form element user agent style in the old angularjs application is:

```
form {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0em;
}
```

But in the new hybrid app build with angular cli it is:

```
form {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
}
```

I thought it might be related to the *browserslist*, but commenting out that file does seem to have any effect.  I have also removed all styles with no luck tracking down why there is a difference.

Any ideas on where to look or what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing:

```
<!doctype html>
```

in my index.html file.  Still not 100% sure why this works in my angularjs 1.7 app but not the hybrid app, but it did fix the problem.